# CakePHP 2.1: Using Set to search for a value

Tags: cakephp, search, set, cakephp-2.1

If have a rather big multidimensional array of the following form (flickr EXIF data).

```
array(
(int) 81 => array(
    'tagspace' => 'Nikon',
    'tagspaceid' => (int) 0,
    'tag' => 'ISOExpansion2',
    'label' => 'ISOExpansion2',
    'raw' => 'Off'
),
(int) 82 => array(
    'tagspace' => 'Nikon',
    'tagspaceid' => (int) 0,
    'tag' => 'LensType',
    'label' => 'Lens Type',
    'raw' => 'G'
),
(int) 83 => array(
    'tagspace' => 'Nikon',
    'tagspaceid' => (int) 0,
    'tag' => 'Lens',
    'label' => 'Lens',
    'raw' => '11-16mm f/2.8'
),...
)
```

Is there a fast and efficient way to extract arrays with certain values, i.e. I would be looking for the value 'Lens' of the key 'Tag' and get an array as return value:

```
array(
    'tagspace' => 'Nikon',
    'tagspaceid' => (int) 0,
    'tag' => 'Lens',
    'label' => 'Lens',
    'raw' => '11-16mm f/2.8'
)
```

Also, can this be done using Set? I have only achieved the following by using `$extract  = Set::classicExtract($exifarray, '{n}.tag')`:

```
array(
      (int) 81 => 'ISOExpansion2',
      (int) 82 => 'LensType',
      (int) 83 => 'Lens',...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set::classicExtract($exifarray, '{n}.tag');` will extract all tags as you've seen.

[Set::matches](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/set#method-Setmatches) ([CakeBook link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set%3a%3amatches)) is used to see if **a single item** or a given xpath match certain conditions.
However **I am not sure if this works with strings**, it should though.
So if you have done:

```
$data = Set::classicExtract($exifarray, '{n}.tag');
```

You can try:

```
foreach($data as $key => $test){
    if(Set:matches(array('0=Lens'), $test[$key])){
    //Logic to run when you have a match.
    }
}
```

If this does not work you will have to do a RegEx match on it in the same "foreach" fashion which by the way may be the right thing to do here.

And a little Note:
[Set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html) is now deprecated (since Cake 2.2). There is a new and better array manipulation class - [Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html). Check it out.